# Rounded Buttons stop working as the Theme of the app changes

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, android-drawable

I have problems with my **rounded_corners.xml** drawable.

I need to have rounded buttons in my app and to do that I've created a **rounded_corners.xml** file, looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFFA00"/>
</shape>
```

and applied it to the buttons like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/rounden_corners"
```

and it works just fine... as long, as the **Theme** of the app in the **AndroidManifest.xml** is default. Which in my case is:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

but as soon as I change it to:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">
```

it stops working. I seems as if the drawable rounded_corners.xml was not recognised.

Here are some screenshots:

[Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R402X.png)
[Theme.MyTheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CreG.png)

Ps: the font and colors of the text change because I have differen values for it in **MyTheme** as in the **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar**

Comment: Hello, is your `MyTheme` inherited from some of `Theme.MaterialComponents` themes?

Comment: @art hi yes it is. This is it: <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

Comment: The question is closed, though you can read about material buttons theming [here](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#theming-buttons).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't find the answer on StackOverflow, but if anyone needed it here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3AZaOekJps